# Making immersive mode working with softkeyboard

Tags: android, keyboard

I use immersive mode to hide navigation bar it works well
But If the keyboard is shown the navigation bar appears with keyboard!
There is anyway to handle this issue
        public void hideSystemUI() {
        final View dm = getWindow().getDecorView();

```
    dm.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {

            dm.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_NAVIGATION// hide status bar
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);

        }
    });

    dm.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION // hide nav bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN // hide status bar
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE);
}
```

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: I updated it
I call this function in onResume
But if the keyboard is shown navigation bar appears below the keyboard again